# Converting KML to feature class using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, kml, feature-class

I am experiencing issues tyring to convert a KML to a layer file to use within ModelBuilder. The KML contains a set of polygon data and a set of polyline data, the polygon data is the data I wish to work with. When I set up the "KML to Layer" within the Model I can't link it to the convert "Feature Class to Feature Class" tool and proceed with my model, it gets stuck at this point. What am I doing wrong?

I am using ArcMap 10.1

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the syntax section of the help file for this tool, what is the output? Then look at the syntax section of the feature class to feature class tool, what is the expected input type? Do they match? This why you should be reading the help file as this explains why the tool will not connect.